# I get an error in User Interface when i use select input

Tags: r, shiny

i am using the following code in my UI

```
  selectInput("param", 
              "Parameter:",
              label = c("S Blood Pressure", "D Blood Pressure"),
              choices = c("SBP", "DBP")
```

i get the following error on my UI page when i run UI.r script.

An error has occurred!
Text to be written must be a length-one character vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you want Parameter to be the label (text to be displayed above the control)

The correct syntax to have a label and a different value for each of the choices in the list:

```r
selectInput("param",
            "Parameter:",
            choices = c("S Blood Pressure" = "SBP", 
                        "D Blood Pressure" = "DBP")),
```